# What is the role of express middleware in feathersjs when hooks can perform the same functionality?

Tags: feathersjs

In the `feathers generate app` command we have a folder called middleware which is used for adding any middleware functionality to the service, however hooks can achieve the same thing, why is middleware provided? Am I missing something?

Comment: The middleware abilities allow you to use standard Express middleware that may have no knowledge of Feathers hooks (like helmet or cors, or to change out the REST error handler).  It also lets you do things like URL rewriting prior to the Feathers service routing.  Note though that anything in that middleware is limited to the REST transport and does nothing w/r/t socket.io etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, hooks can do almost anything an Express middleware can do. The difference is that they are *transport independent*. This means that hooks will work no matter if you use the service internally, through a websocket (Socket.io), HTTP (Express) or any other kind of connection. I wrote more about the benefits of this transport independent design in [Design patterns for modern web APIs](https://blog.feathersjs.com/design-patterns-for-modern-web-apis-1f046635215).

Feathers is fully compatible with Express which means that normal middleware is still available to you but most Feathers apps have only very few or usually no middleware at all. The reason why you would still use Express middleware (which does not run when using a Socket.io connection) is to convert from and to things that are specific to the HTTP request and responses. That way services and hooks can process it in a way where they don't have to know about where this information is coming from. Some examples are

- Parsing headers or signatures in a [custom service middleware](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#custom-service-middleware)
- Formatting a response in a different format [like a CSV download](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#custom-service-middleware)
- [Browser file uploads](https://docs.feathersjs.com/cookbook/express/file-uploading.html)

For anything else you can and should use a hook. That way your application will stay future proof and you won't have to change anything when moving to a different transport mechanism.

Comment: So in express middleware I have access to the standard request, response and the next middleware. Actually I was having trouble writing the mongoose aggregation pipeline using hooks, so can I use express middleware to handle that functionality? Or if I were to write the aggregation pipeline using hook how to I send a result of the pipeline operation to the clinet

Comment: I have to create a custom route for 3DS URL fallback. I assume an express middleware would be better for that. However, how to properly access the application in order to call services on that middleware if that is even doable?